# SurfaceTexture.getTimestamp() returning 0 during playback

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec, grafika

Recently I've encountered a strange problem on Android 5.0.2 (API 21). My application is using SurfaceTexture to display video. Playback mechanics are mostly based on [google/grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika)'s CameraCaptureAvtivity, but the video source is decoded .mp4 movie file instead of camera. The application worked just fine until I ran it on Galaxy S6 with Android 5.0.2 (I successfully used devices with 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 before that). The problem is that each time I try to recieve timestamp from SurfaceTexture with `getTimestamp()`, the method returns 0, though playback is fine. On the other devices I've mentioned before the timestamp was correct. 
 Can someone tell me if this might be Android bug? Is there any way to work it around?

Comment: Is it always zero, or do you get one zero and then it goes back to returning reasonable values? I used to see one frame with a zero timestamp after toggling the power off and on, but didn't have a chance to track it down. You can see a reference to it in https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureMovieEncoder.java#L204 .

Comment: @fadden You're right, situation you're describing happens to me on 4.4.2 and 4.4.4, and I can handle it with no problems. Unfortunately,  on Android 5.0.2 timestamp I'm getting from getTimestamp() is always zero during the whole playback. I'm also using TextureMovieEncoder you mentioned for encoding video to file, so I need this timestamp to be valid.

Comment: Weird. Unfortunately I'm no longer in a position to investigate. Might be worth filing a bug on http://b.android.com/ .

Comment: As far as I can tell, MediaPlayer does still properly set the timestamp, but MediaCodec stopped in 5.0.2.  Not much info, I know.

Comment: @Mog I didn't notice any other bugs with decoding other then this on 5.0.2 (I'm not even really sure if this would be MediaDecoder problem). As of MediaPlayer, I'm not familiar with it, my project does not use it because of some more sophisticated requirements. I filled a bug as fadden suggested and worked this around in the end.

Comment: Hi, how tit you please worked this around? Is there a way to add timestamp manually to SurfaceTexture? I found this to be problem for me in one project...

Comment: @kvgr If I recall it correctly, the timestamp was used while encoding displayed video. So instead of using the bugged timestamp from SurfaceTexture, I was continuously storing timestamps from decoder's MediaCodec.BufferInfo. They were used in encoder eventually. I hope this helps.